# Mongoose did not sent the data as expected

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I had a mongoose object at server side:

```
...
item = {
  name: "Test",
  id: 1
}

// item's an mongo schema

// id and name defined in model as String and Number
```

Then I add into item new field mentions:

```
item.mention = [{ id: 1, ... }]
```

But I can't get mention at client side.

My response code:

```
res,json({ status: 1, message: 'success', data: item })
```

The response was data: `{ name: "Test", id: 1 }`

I don't want to add mention into my mongo schema.

So, what's my problem?

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mongoose will not allow you to modify item document if a field you are trying to set value for does not exists in schema of the model, which is your case is "mention" field.
If you want to add "mention" field you have to access _doc field of the item document. Example :-

```
item._doc.mention = [{ id: 1, ... }]
```

Response should be:-

```
{ name: "Test", id: 1, mention: [{ id: 1, ... }] }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not usually recommended, but if you want to change schema like this.
you should pass strict false parameter to mongoose model while setting schema like this.

```
var ModelSchema = new Schema({
  number: String,
}, { strict: false });
```

Now, it will change schema if you give any other parameter which is not in schema, it will add that one.